# php - From MySQL to CSS

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a own CMS and want the user to be able to write some css (choose their own background-image, link color, text color, etc).

I've been looking for a way to save CSS code into a MySQL-tabel and then ofcourse retrieve it from the database back to the .css-file.

I found this [Turtorial](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/)
It doesn't really show how to use a database with it but I am thinking it would be good start doing like this and then echo out from the database instead of the variables. But I don't seem to make it work. This is the code so far:

main.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

require '../app/start.php';

$css = $db->query("
    SELECT textColor, linkColor, background
    FROM css
    WHERE id=1
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

body {
background: url('<?php echo $css['background']; ?>') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

start.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/views');
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost:8080/mypage/public_html');

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mycms', 'root', '');

require 'functions.php';
```

In the database at the background column I have just a random image-url to see if it works (http://all4desktop.com/data_images/original/4238051-background.jpg)

Comment: `$css` is a multi-dminesional array, isn't it? What does the page generate currently? Any errors? `don't seem to make it work` isn't a really good description of what currently is happening.

Comment: The css-table is made of an "ID" wich is 1, and "textColor", "linkColor", "background". When the user changes these, I am thinking I will go with ALTER TABLE, it should work if I don't think completely wrong, right? The page doesn't give any errors, it shows everything as it should, except the CSS from this database.

Comment: Look at the source and the errors logs. What is in both places. It think your `css` currently would display `Array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*fetchAll* returns an array of records, which are arrays of key/value pairs. As a consequence `$css['background']` does not exist. However `$css[0]['background']` does (provided there was a record found).

But it seems your table would have at the most one record per user, so what you'll want to do is replace that *fetchAll* with just *fetch*. Then `$css['background']` makes sense.

Make sure though to deal well with the situation where there is no record found. In that case *$css* will be `false`, and any reference to *$css* as an array will then produce an error.